# Use of Excluded Variables Table on Multiple Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, data-visualization

I'm currently running a multiple regression analysis as part of my first year PhD study, trying to predict Theory of Mind through 2 variables of interest while controlling for socio-demographic data. I did this by entering the variables in a hierarchical multiple regression as it follows:

- Model 1 (Sociocemographic Variables): AGE (dummy coded), GENDER standardised)
- Model 2 (Variables of Interest): IV1 and IV2 (both standardised).
- Model 3 (Interactions 1): IV1*IV2
- Model 4 (Interactions 2): IV1*AGE and IV1*GENDER
- Model 5 (Interactions 3): IV2*AGE and IV2*GENDER

I checked the significance of each model and the R2 Change to select the appropriate model, then proceeded to check which variables resulted significant inside that model and report them.

My question is, would it be correct to report also the variables that resulted significant in the Excluded Variables Table for the correspondent model? I've read that this table shows if a variable may result significant if entered on an hypothetical next model but I'm not sure if:

1. This should be limited only for stepwise method only, or if it can be used with (for example) enter method as a complementary result.
2. If it can be done and in case the variable is an interaction term, it would be correct to plot it with this tool (http://www.jeremydawson.co.uk/slopes.htm).
3. And if so, would it be correct to transform the Beta value (Excluded Variable Table only provides Standardised Coef.) to Unstandardised Coefficient by dividing Beta by the ratio of the SD of the IV and DV)?

Thank in advance, let me know if you need more info!

Jose S.